# Invalid Column name can't use variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an error invalid column name on the last select statement in my procedure. I need to get the `ThreadTitle` and it is selected by the Column `ThreadID`. I can't use a local variable and set it because of the `F.ForumD` select clause. I just need to get the `ThreadID` and pass it to the `ThreadTitle` does anyone know how to do that

```
SELECT ForumGroup = (
  CASE WHEN ParentID IS NOT NULL THEN
    (SELECT Title FROM Forums WHERE ForumID = F.ParentID)           
  ELSE
    (SELECT Title FROM Forums WHERE ParentID IS NULL)
  END),
  Title, 
  Description, 
  ThreadCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts P WHERE  P.ForumID = F.ForumID),
  LastPostBy = (SELECT TOP 1 AddedBy FROM Posts P 
    WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC), 
  LastPostDate = (SELECT TOP 1 AddedDate FROM Posts P 
    WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC), 
  LastPostTitle = (SELECT TOP 1 Title FROM Posts P 
    WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC),
  ThreadID =  CAST(SUBSTRING((SELECT TOP 1 Path_String 
    FROM Posts P WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC), 0, 
    CHARINDEX('/', (SELECT TOP 1 Path_String FROM Posts P 
    WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC))) AS INT),
  ThreadTitle = (SELECT TOP 1 Title FROM Posts P 
    WHERE P.PostID = ThreadID ORDER BY P.PostID DESC) 
  FROM Forums F WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY Title
```

Comment: How is this related to C# or ASP.NET? It is a pure [t-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) question.

Comment: Can you post the two create table statements?  It would be really helpful if you also could give some example inserts together with the expected results.

Comment: What is the difference between the post title and the thread title? Is there a threads table that you forgot to mention/reference?

Comment: Please take the time to format your code/SQL so it's readable. If you don't use tab characters (spaces instead), indent as needed, and break long lines to avoid horizontal scrolling, it makes it much more readable (and therefore likely to be answered). You can preview your post realtime while entering it by looking just below where you're inputting the question. (And formatting it yourself means others don't have to spend their time doing it and can try to provide answers instead. <g>) Thanks. :)

Comment: I don't understand the `ForumGroup` calculation. You have `WHERE ForumGroup IS NOT NULL` so the `CASE` doesn't make any sense - it can only ever be `NOT NULL` since your `WHERE` clause eliminates all `NULL`s.

Comment: my case Forums table also has ForumFroups thats why there is a case statement in there

Comment: Please post create table statements, sample data and desired results. Otherwise we're just trying to reverse engineer spaghetti.

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have all the schema, I'm going to take some liberties with both assumptions about what you have and suggestions about what you should have. You should take these with a grain of salt because they are geared to satisfying this query, and I have no idea what other queries these suggestions may impact.

I'm going to guess at the base tables:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Forums
(
    ForumID     INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title       VARCHAR(32),
    Description VARCHAR(255),
    ParentID    INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Forums(ForumID)
);
CREATE INDEX t ON dbo.Forums(ParentID);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Threads
(
    ThreadID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title    VARCHAR(32)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Posts
(
    PostID      INT PRIMARY KEY,
    AddedBy     VARCHAR(32),
    AddedDate   DATETIME, 
    Title       VARCHAR(32),
    Path_String VARCHAR(255),
    ForumID     INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Forums(ForumID)
);
CREATE INDEX f ON dbo.Posts(ForumID, PostID DESC) INCLUDE(AddedBy, AddedDate, Title);
GO
```

Now, because `Path_String` is almost certainly written only once, you may benefit greatly from making this a persisted computed column and indexing it. This way you pay the penalty of calculating that expensive substring only when the row is inserted, and not every time you run a query.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Posts ADD ThreadID AS 
    CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Path_String, 0, CHARINDEX('/', Path_String))) 
    PERSISTED FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Threads(ThreadID);

CREATE INDEX t ON dbo.Posts(ThreadID);

CREATE INDEX f ON dbo.Posts(ForumID, PostID DESC) 
    INCLUDE(AddedBy, AddedDate, Title, ThreadID) WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
GO
```

With these things in place, your query can be re-written as:

```
;WITH p AS
(
    SELECT PostID, AddedBy, AddedDate, Title, ForumID, ThreadID, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ForumID ORDER BY PostID DESC),
        c  = COUNT(*)     OVER (PARTITION BY ForumID)
    FROM dbo.Posts
)
SELECT
    ForumGroup    = fp.Title,
    f.Title,
    f.Description,
    ThreadCount   = p.c,
    LastPostBy    = p.AddedBy,
    LastPostDate  = p.AddedDate,
    LastPostTitle = p.Title,
    ThreadID      = p.ThreadID,
    ThreadTitle   = t.Title
FROM dbo.Forums AS f
  INNER JOIN p                      ON p.ForumID  = f.ForumID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Threads AS t  ON t.ThreadID = p.ThreadID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Forums  AS fp ON fp.ForumID = f.ParentID
WHERE p.rn = 1
AND f.ParentID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY f.Title;
```

Feel free to compare the execution plans. You'll see a lot more scans/seeks/nested loops in your version of the query because of all the subqueries you used.

Of course, without sample data and desired results, I have no idea if the query you've written (which I based my answer off of) was even getting you the results you needed. But hopefully you will come around and provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

fre you trying to get the TreadID in select statement to use in place of TreadID in last select? if so u can use same query and replace it with TreadID.

```
    SELECT ForumGroup = ( 
      CASE WHEN ParentID IS NOT NULL THEN 
        (SELECT Title FROM Forums WHERE ForumID = F.ParentID)            
      ELSE 
        (SELECT Title FROM Forums WHERE ParentID IS NULL) 
      END), 
      Title,  
      Description,  
      ThreadCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                     FROM Posts P 
                     WHERE  P.ForumID = F.ForumID), 
      LastPostBy = (SELECT TOP 1 AddedBy 
                    FROM Posts P  
                    WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID 
                    ORDER BY P.PostID DESC),  
      LastPostDate = (SELECT TOP 1 AddedDate 
                      FROM Posts P  
                      WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID 
                      ORDER BY P.PostID DESC),  
      LastPostTitle = (SELECT TOP 1 Title 
                       FROM Posts P  
                       WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID 
                       ORDER BY P.PostID DESC), 
      ThreadID =  CAST(SUBSTRING((SELECT TOP 1 Path_String  
                                  FROM Posts P 
                                  WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID 
                                  ORDER BY P.PostID DESC), 0,  CHARINDEX('/', (SELECT TOP 1 Path_String 
                                                                               FROM Posts P  
                                                                               WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID 
                                                                               ORDER BY P.PostID DESC)
                                                                        )
                                ) AS INT), 
      ThreadTitle = (SELECT TOP 1 Title 
                     FROM Posts P  
                     WHERE P.PostID = (CAST(SUBSTRING((SELECT TOP 1 Path_String  
                                                        FROM Posts P 
                                                        WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID 
                                                        ORDER BY P.PostID DESC), 0,  CHARINDEX('/', (SELECT TOP 1 Path_String 
                                                                                                     FROM Posts P  
                                                                                                     WHERE P.ForumID = F.ForumID 
                                                                                                     ORDER BY P.PostID DESC)
                                                                                               )
                                                       ) AS INT)) 
                    ORDER BY P.PostID DESC
                    )  
      FROM Forums F WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL 
      ORDER BY Title
```

Comment: I don't think ThreadTitle and PostTitle are the same (in other words, ThreadTitle shouldn't come from the Posts table).

Comment: I am not saying that.. his query had that.. i dont know dataschema.. i gave my answer based on what i understand from @KDM's question.